# parallax scrolling doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I need your assistance with parallax scrolling. 
I'm working on this website - new.rangafner.com

There are 2 parallax sections - #intro & #shows.
The #intro works properly, #shows doesn't.

It starts from the middle for some reason.

This is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// cache the window object
$window = $(window);
$('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
 // declare the variable to affect the defined data-type
 var $scroll = $(this);

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    // HTML5 proves useful for helping with creating JS functions!
    // also, negative value because we're scrolling upwards                             
    var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $scroll.data('speed')); 

    // background position
    var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

    // move the background
    $scroll.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });    
  }); // end window scroll
 });  // end section function
}); // close out script
```

and this is the css for the background image:

```
    #shows { 
    background: url(../images/shows_page_bg&pic.jpg) 50% 1000px fixed no-repeat; 
    height: 750px;  
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 100%; 
    position: relative; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    padding: 100px 0;
    min-height: 750px;
}
```

Would love your help with this.
Thanks.

Comment: What are your image dimensions? What you mean by not working? Is it not showing or not changing?

Comment: You can go to new.rangafner.com and scroll down to the #shows section. 
it seems like the background image is not starting in the right position. (This is the section with the guy with the cube).

Comment: On my IE (edge) is working. But try changing the `var yPos = -Math.floor($window.scrollTop() / $scroll.data('speed'));` to get rid of this shaking effect.

Comment: it's not shaking. it's starts about 200px before it should...